# MySQL exclude rows subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm trying to get all rows but avoid those with 'departing' entry on "status" column.

**I want to know that 'trips' have 'arrived' as 'status'  but exclude those that already have 'departing' as 'status'.**

I already tried with `GROUP BY DISTINCT` (without the desired result).

Datatabse:

```
id  trip    type    status      date
1   1260    ocean   arriving    2019-03-04
2   1260    ocean   departing   2019-03-05
3   1261    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
4   1262    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
5   1263    ocean   arriving    2019-03-08
6   1263    ocean   departing   2019-03-09
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `status` NOT IN (select `status` FROM `test` WHERE `status` =  'departing')

Result:
                id  trip    type    status      date
                1   1260    ocean   arriving    2019-03-04
                3   1261    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
                4   1262    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
                5   1263    ocean   arriving    2019-03-08
```

Desired result:

```
                    id  trip    type    status      date
                    3   1261    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
                    4   1262    ocean   arriving    2019-03-05
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec331/3

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to filter out the 'arriving' rows that have the same `trip` as the 'departing' rows? It's all I can assume looking at the sample data in the SQL Fiddle; you may want to update the question with the sample data and a clear statement of what you're looking for.

Comment: Your query is equivalent to: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE status <>'departing'`. Now you should explain what is so special about the rows that you want as a result.

Comment: @cteski I'm sorry. I want to know that 'trips' have 'arrived' as 'status'  but exclude those that already have 'departing' as 'status'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `not exists`:

```
select * 
from test t
where status = 'arriving'
  and not exists (select 1 from test
                  where trip = t.trip and status = 'departing')
```

I'm not sure if you want the subquery's condition maybe like this:

```
where trip = t.trip and status = 'departing' and date > t.date
```

Comment: Thanks @Forpas, this worked! I was using a wrong statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'date' column and use a value as a parameter

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE status <> 'departing' and date = '2019-03-05'`

See this example:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec331/18

Comment: thank you but the dates are not a viable way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query. it only show rows where the trip number is only in 1 row.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `trip` IN (
  select trip FROM `test` group by trip
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one does not work for me because if the number of 'trip' is registered again then it will stop showing it

Answer (score 0):

For this example I would group the results in a nested where clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE status = 'arriving' AND trip IN (SELECT trip FROM test GROUP BY trip HAVING count(trip) = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one does not work for me because if the number of 'trip' is registered again then it will stop showing it.